# Sharing text to social networks, xamarin.forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, share

I've been trying to implement a share feature of text to social platforms. My attempted code using DependencyService returns my text only in the "subject" of my email. When I try to copy the text to my clipboard, this does not work. Nor does the text pass to any of the other social platforms. Please view code below. Is there anything I'm missing?

**IShareService(Interface class)**

```
public interface IShareService
    {
        void SharePageLink(string link);
    }
```

**ShareService(Class in Android project)**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ShareService))]
namespace LoyaltyWorx.Droid
{
    public class ShareService: IShareService
    {
        public void SharePageLink(string text)
        {
            var context = Forms.Context;
            Activity activity = context as Activity;

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            share.SetType("text/plain");
            share.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
            share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Cool");
            share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, text);

            activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Share text!"));

        }

    }
}
```

**Promotions.xaml.cs (The text to share)**

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string shareText = "Promotion: " + store + "- " + description;
            DependencyService.Get<IShareService>().SharePageLink(shareText);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Share plugin](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) in Xamarin.Forms to share a message or link, copy text to clipboard, or open a browser in any Xamarin or Windows app.

Add Plugin.Share Reference in the Portable, Android and UWP projects, and use like this:

```
using Plugin.Share; 

void OpenBrowser() {  
    CrossShare.Current.OpenBrowser("http://www.google.com");  
}  
void TextShare() {  
    CrossShare.Current.Share("Share Text", "Sample Title");  
}  
void LinkShare() {  
    CrossShare.Current.ShareLink("Link To Share", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/");  
}
```

For more detail refer to [this](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin/tree/master/docs) official doc.